# Vertical line on my website CSS + scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, safari, line

I'm having an issue with viewing my site in other browsers under Windows OS. There appears an vertical line on the right of the site (marked with the arrow). I thought it's a scroll bar but I was wrong. My MacBook shows it all right while a 13 inch toshiba takes it wrong. The same problem is on a 15" win computer. Here is the css code of my div.

Another issue is that the scrollbar appear when using mozilla - to looks ugly, but when using "overflow:hidden" property it disables scrolling. Any idea how to solve those annoying problems?

```
.container { 
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative; 
 background-color: #0099cc; 
 padding-top: 120px; 
 text-align: center; 
 white-space: nowrap; 
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #888; 
 height: 100%; 
 min-width: 1280px; 
 min-height: 800px; 
 overflow: scroll; 
 }
```

image link:
[ugly line on the right](http://s1.postimg.org/n0thmt8nj/error.png)

Website:
[site with the issue](http://annawruk.com.pl)

Comment: provide some HTML code or you website link to work with ?

Comment: Seems that "ugly line" is actually the background of the containing element. So we would indeed need more to work with here (eventualy a dumbed down code just to reproduce the issue - this is usually the best way to identify where problems come from, and in this case it might come down to just your green container and its parent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 'ugly' lines are just inactive scrollbars, you can remove them by making `overflow:visible;` on your divs. But I don't know if this will affect your website in other ways.

Comment: It doesn't help. The inactive scrollbars are still there, though they are now active and available to scroll around…

Comment: Really? It worked for me, I tried it in .container

Comment: Ok, I've changed it and uploaded the css file. I'm confused because my Mac version of Chrome is showing the content as I'd like it to but still my friend says there is the inactive scrollbar on his win. In fact, the content was good on my mac without any necessary modifications. You are telling me that it is ok after on your win chrome? - it's really annoying to work this out for me…

Comment: Yep, actually if I visit your website using Chrome or Firefox on Windows, the scrollbars disappeared. Still, there is in Firefox an empty black if I scroll to the right.

Comment: Any sugestion how to remove that black space on the right?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Try to post another question about that problem.